# Formula Calculator Form

Tags: php, calculated-field

I am looking to build a simple one-field form that will take the number entered and run it through a formula and display the result underneath on a webpage for a school project.  Similar to a paypal fee calculator.  NO more, no less.

I can handle HTML, CSS, JS, but am pretty PHP-tarded.

Is there something I can read to learn how to go about this?  I tried searching but am not sure exactly what I should be searching for.

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you could do this entirely in Javascript.

Comment: You don't need PHP for this. Just use Javascript.

Comment: If you must use php (maybe the project requires it), you should be able to google something like `PHP forms tutorial` to get the basics of what you need.

Comment: Yes, you _could_ do it with JavaScript, as previous commenters have said. Don't let that deter you, however: it's entirely possible to do with PHP, too. But you need to show some minimal understanding of how to solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the responses.  I do not have to use PHP, I just figured that is what is typically used for forms.  I would prefer JS if possible, but do not know where to start.  Is there any examples out there I can use to begin?
I am simply adding this to my webpage for a school project to increase the 'wow' factor.  Non-Warcraft related.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Name the field that you are entering, i.e.

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="value" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php
$value=$_POST['value'];
if ($value!=""){
    //RUN FORMULA HERE:
    $total=$value * 1.02;
    echo $total;
}
?>
```

Using this method will allow you to continue entering numbers until you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Next time see php manual or google... there is a lot of similars...

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['number']))
{
?>
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" value=0 name='number'/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<?php
}
else
{
$num = $_POST['number'];
$result = ($num * $num) + $num;
echo $result;
}
?>
```